# Diferencia entre FOR y FOR EACH

Tags: loops

Un compañero y yo acabamos de tener un debate interesante:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre `For` y `For Each`?

En código ya se como funciona, pero ¿y por detras? ¿Realmente que es lo mas recomendable? ¿En que casos deberiamos usar uno y en cuales el otro?

Teniendo en cuenta rapidez, memoria, etc...

Aquí os dejo una [referencia](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach) bastante interesante, pero creo que se podria aclarar mas la cosa.

Comment: Duda, ¿Como se etiquetan este tipo de preguntas? Se que lo lei en meta pero ya no lo recuerdo.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? El bucle `for-each` puede tener matices muy diferentes según el lenguaje.

Comment: En general, aplicado a todos. Yo especialmente voy por web, (php,js,.net,c#,...). Aunque haya matices, ¿creo que el uso de memoria, rapidez y a que estan destinados no cambiaran mucho verdad? yo lo uso para lo mismo en todos lados, ¿¿pero y si es recomendable no usarlo en unos casos y en otros si??

Comment: Pues en general, el bucle `for-each` de [tag:php] es muy diferente al bucle `for-each` de [tag:.net] que a su vez es diferente al bucle `for-each` de [tag:c#] que es muy diferente al bucle `for-each` de [tag:c++]...

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster me estas dejando alucinado :O y tanto se diferencian? podrias colocar algunas de las diferencias almenos para poder indentificarlas. Ya lo etiqueto con los lenguajes que pongas.

Comment: Soy experto en C++ y puedo responder por C++ hasta muy bajo nivel, por desgracia no puedo bajar a nivel tan técnico en otros lenguajes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65640/discussion-between-gdp-and-paperbirdmaster).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La principal diferencia, en la mayoría de los lenguajes, es que un `for` itera sobre cosas **que no tienen porqué existir**, y nos garantiza el orden de acceso; por su parte, un `for-each` itera sobre cosas que, obligatoriamente, **han de existir**. Además, **no nos garantiza** el orden en el que se accede.

#### En *PHP*

```
for( $a = 0; $a < 5; $a++ ) {
  ...
}
```

Como se ve, el `for` recorrería el rango de valores `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, pero **ninguno de ellos existe** antes del propio `for`. No se recorre una lista de nada; los valores se generan sobre la marcha, y se comprueba si cumplen o no la condición.

```
foreach( $arr as $v ) {
  ...
}
```

En este caso, **se itera sobre el contenido** de un *arreglo*. Dicho *arreglo* **ha de existir con anterioridad**. No se va *auto-generando*; los valores se toman de una lista **previamente existente**.

```
foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) {
  ...
}
```

Apenas sutilmente diferente del anterior. Los valores, igualmente, **se toman de una lista ya existente**.

#### C++

```
for( idx = 0; idx < 5; ++idx ) {
  ..
}
```

Practicamente idéntico a *PHP*. Se auto-genera un valor, y se comprueba que cumpla cierta condición. Dicho valor **no tienen porqué existir** *fuera* del `for`.

```
for( idx: container ) {
  ...
}
```

Se recorre un *contenedor*, desde su primer elemento hasta al último.

Bueno, el caso de C++ es *distinto*. Se llama a cierta función de un objeto, y el objeto resultante se va actualizando mientras se cumpla cierta condición. Como las funciones implicadas son generadas por el usuario ... pues en realidad **no tenemos ni idea** de si los valores existían con anterioridad al `for`. Puede considerarse un caso *extremo* de polivalencia.

No obstante, esta forma se introdujo para facilitar el uso de los contenedores; así que, en su concepción *original*, podemos concluir que, al igual que *PHP*, se recorre una lista de elementos **que existían con anterioridad** al `for`.

#### Tendencias

Parece que la tendencia es hacia la forma `for-each` del lenguaje C++; realizar llamadas a funciones auxiliares que son las que realmente nos proporcionan el valor **real** a tratar.

Esta forma de trabajar es **muy polivalente**, pero implica cierto *sobrecoste* (por norma, sobre todo en lenguajes no compilados, una llamada a una función es *mas costosa* que llamar a un operador proporcionado por el lenguaje).

#### Eficiencia en su uso con contenedores

En el caso de querer *iterar* sobre los datos de un contenedor, en lenguajes no-compilados, suele ser mas rápido la forma `for-each`.

Esto ya se sale de la temática, pero, a *groso-modo*, en lenguajes interpretados, los *objetos* o *diccionarios* o como se llamen suelen estar implementados mediante árboles o mediante tablas *hash* (menos frecuente).

Al estar implementados mediante árboles, acceder desde un nodo al siguiente es *relativamente fácil*; basta con acceder a un *puntero*, lo cual es poco menos que inmediato (la forma `for-each` **no garantiza** el orden en el que se visitará los distintos valores).

Sin embargo, acceder al elemento `Contenedor[5]` conlleva recorrer el árbol, desde su raiz, comparando las claves hasta dar con la buscada. Bastante mas lento que el caso anterior.

Answer (score 7):

Tocho "abuelo cebolleta", aviso:

Cada lenguaje tiene su variante, pero, si nos vamos al concepto original, el bucle for era un bucle con un número determinado (antes de iniciarse) de iteraciones:

```
for i=0 to 30 do
  ...
end
```

Si no sabías el número de iteraciones de antemano, entonces tenías que usar, obligatoriamente, un bucle while:

```
while (condición) do
  ...
end
```

Esto estaba tan asumido que en lenguajes como Pascal o Modula-2, la condición se establecía al inicio y era inmutable. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
n=5;
for i=1 to n do
  n=n+1
end
```

No producía un bucle infinito, sino que se ejecutaba 5 veces, aunque n fuese 10 tras la última iteración, porque la condición se comprobaba con respecto al valor de n al inicio del bucle.

Pero entonces llegó C y creó un for "bastardo", mezclando for y while:

```
for (inicialización; condición; código) {
 ... 
}
```

La sintaxis de este for ni siquiera obliga a usar un contador o tener código en el cuerpo del bucle:

```
for ( ; int elem=pila.pop()!=null; otraPila.push(elem));
```

Así que tenemos que hoy día no hay diferencia entre while y for

El bucle forEach es casi una vuelta a los orígenes: mientras no uses un `break`, el número de iteraciones es el número de elementos de la colección que estás recorriendo. Pero este bucle sólo aporta una sintaxis más sencilla, la funcionalidad es incluso menor que la del bucle for "clásico" puesto que no sabemos el índice del elemento y por tanto no podemos hacer algo tan básico como borrarlo o sustituirlo por otro en la colección que estamos recorriendo. Ejemplo en Java:

```
for(Object o: collectionOfObjects) {

}
```

En lenguajes más funcionales, como javascript o Java 8, le han dado una vuelta más de tuerca para favorecer el paralelismo y directamente tenemos una función que oculta el bucle:

```
myArray.forEach(function (item, index) {...});
```

y que tampoco se puede parar, por lo que se han creado otras funciones como some, filter, find... que no obligan a recorrer toda la colección.

Fin del tocho. Ahora respondo a la pregunta ¿cuál usar?:

Usa el que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades: el bucle forEach tiene una sintaxis más clara, no requiere declarar un índice y en la mayoría de los casos el compilador lo transformará en un bucle for clásico (en Java usando un iterador, por ejemplo), con lo que el rendimiento será bastante similar.

Comment: Yo añadiría que mientras estás recorriendo un listado (por ejemplo), si lo haces a través de un bucle foreach (al menos en c#) no puedes modificar un elemento sobre el que estás iterando aunque si que puedes modificar sus propiedades. El bucle for te da más libertad para eso aunque más libertad suponga más riesgo y más facilidad de generar errores

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano, si puedes modificar su valor si lo pasas por referencia, tal como: arr.forEach(function(part, index, array) {
  array[index] = "Valor";
});

Comment: @JoseFG Eso es modificar un atributo, PabloSimonDiEstefano se refiere a sustituir directamente el objeto entero en la colección

Comment: Cierto, releyéndolo había entendido mal la parte de "no puedes modificar un elemento sobre el que estás iterando". ;)

Comment: @PabloLozano, no se si se puede hacer lo que me dices (En todo momento estoy hablando de listas en c#, ahí no puedes hacer lista.forEach...) o eso o no lo entiendo :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo pienso que depende de la necesidad usarás uno u otro.

- El `for-each` es mas cómodo en lo que a sintaxis se refiere y su lectura es sencilla y clara. Lo que es una ventaja
- El `for` es mucho mas ambiguo en ese sentido y añade un poco mas de complejidad y tienes más posibilidad de equivocarte en algún parámetro.

Todo esto respecto al **estilo** pero diferencias en **performance** (*por detrás*) tengo entendido que son prácticamente pocas por no decir **ninguna**, a ojos de usuario.

Otra cosa es saber de que lenguaje hablamos ya que de Javascript a C++ pasando por C#

Comment: Lo que mas me ha llamado la atencion es esta parte:
El bucle for es más rápido que el bucle foreach si sólo se debe acceder a la matriz una vez por iteración.

Comment: La diferencia en rendimiento será muy dependiente de la implementación, lo cual (en el caso del for-each) variará según sea la implementación de la colección recorrida.