# Recorrido matriz y comparación en busca de coincidencias

Tags: java, matrices, bucle-for

Buenas! He estado buscando y no he encontrado nada que me ayudase, tampoco se si hay otra manera.

Tengo una matriz de números y quiero buscar los valores que están repetidos. Lo he conseguido con 4 bucles pero lo encuentro bruto.

Mi pregunta és que si hay otra forma de hacerlo que sea mas clara.

```
for (int a = 0; a < matriuN.length; a++){
    for (int b = 0; b < matriuN.length; b++){
        //con 'a' y 'b' cogeremos el valor de referencia
        for (int c = 0; c < matriuN.length; c++){
            for (int d = b + 1; d < matriuN.length; d++){
                //con 'c' y 'd' iremos recorriendo la matriz
                if (matriuN[a][b] == matriuN[c][d]){
                    System.out.println("Coincidencia!" + matriuN[a][b]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dices, sí es un poco bruto hacerlo con cuatro bucles.

Si lo único que necesitas hacer es mostrar aquellos que están repetidos, una forma simple sería recorrer la matriz y, con cada valor, meterlo en un Map donde la clave sería el valor que has leído y el valor, un contador de las veces que has leído ese valor.

Cada vez que actualices el valor de un contador, si es 2, será la primera vez que encuentras una repetición, así que lo escribes en la salida. Si es mayor que 2, como ya lo habrás encontrado antes, lo ignoras y sigues.

Con esta solución, encontrarías los repetidos con sólo dos bucles anidados.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, Jordi.

Te ofrezco una alternativa, seguramente dentro de muchas otras, y es haciendo uso de la instrucción *foreach*. Para el caso del lenguaje de programación **Java** la sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
for (int value: matriuN) {
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

De acuerdo a tu consulta en la que mencionas el uso de matrices la sintaxis sería:

**(1)**

```
for (int[] array_a: matriuN) {
  for (int value: array_a) {
    System.out.print(value + " ");
  }
}
```

Es por ellos que si tienes la siguiente matriz:

```
int[][] matriuN = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

Haciendo uso de lo expuesto en **(1)** el resultado será:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

De esta forma entonces, puedes presentar tu código de una manera más clara y un poco menos extensa, sin embargo quiero aclararte unas de las diferencias entre las instrucciones *for* y *foreach*.

La instrucción *for* es muy útil cuando debes recorrer un arreglo de cualquier dimensión y necesitas hacerlo de acuerdo a una serie de condiciones, digamos una muy simple, quieres recorrerlo a partir de la posición 2, por lo que sería:

```
for (int i = 2; i < ...) { ..
```

Por el contrario la instrucción *foreach* se utiliza comunmente cuando vas a recorrer el arreglo de una manera más *plana*, además es más fácil de comprender.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Te comparto este tema que puede aclararte otras cosas sobre las instrucciones mencionadas.

[Diferencia entre FOR y FOR EACH](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102524/diferencia-entre-for-y-for-each)