# Recorrer un array en Java con un bucle for según el número de elementos

Tags: java

Usando un bucle **for** para *recorrer un array* según su número de elementos, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre las siguientes alternativas?

```
// Primera opción
int size = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    ...
}

// Segunda opción
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    ...
}

// Tercera opción
for (int e : arr) {
    ...
}
```

Si no necesito el número de iteración para hacer operaciones utilizó la última opción, en caso contrario: la primera frente a la segunda. Me parece más legible la primera opción que la segunda, lo que no se es si hay diferencias de rendimiento entre las dos primeras, siempre me ha parecido que se calcula la longitud del array para cada iteración, pero no se si esto es así.

Comment: Creo que este post puede responder a tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102524/diferencia-entre-for-y-for-each

Comment: @unanobot el post contiene una respuesta más bien genérica, y aunque trata bucles en PHP y C++, no aparece el caso de Java. Las implementaciones pueden variar mucho entre lenguajes, en cuanto a consumo de memoria, rendimiento, etc. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

La primera opción declara una variable externa que continuará existiendo cuando se termine de iterar. Adicionalmente, te proporciona la posibilidad de iterar un bucle en los dos sentidos o de reducir o ampliar la cantidad de iteraciones durante la ejecución. Su desventaja es que creas una variable extra en memoria y que el código es menos legible (explicaré la legibilidad luego).

En cuanto a lo que a modificar las veces que se ejecuta: imagina que quieres comparar si el primer elemento es igual al último, el segundo igual al penúltimo... etc:

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == arr[arr.length-1-i]){
        System.out.println("Son iguales");
    }
}
```

Pero compararías 2 veces todos los elementos (en la primera iteración compararías el primer y el último elemento y en la última iteración compararías el último y el primero. Voy a obviar la solución simple porque no sirve para ilustrar este ejemplo y que sería recorrer el array hasta la mitad. Otra forma de hacerlo sería reducir las iteraciones en tiempo de ejecución:

```
int longitud = arr.length;
for(int i =0; i<=longitud; i++){
    if(arr[i] == arr[longitud-1]{
        System.out.println("Son iguales");
    }
    longitud--;
}
```

Atento a que la longitud se reduce cada iteración cuando se ejecuta `longitud--;`, por lo que el bucle se ejecutará la mitad de veces.

---

En lo que a legibilidad se refiere, puede que parezca que, efectivamente es más legible del primer modo, pero una vez te acostumbras a verlo escrito no te plantea más dificultades, sin embargo declarar una variable sólamente para eso tiene un contra muy grande: No tiene por qué estar junto como tú lo has puesto y conduce a errores, supongamos que tienes 2 arrays inicializados y llenos llamados arr1 y arr2:

```
int longitud = arr2.length;

[Bloque grande de código]

for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
    System.out.println(arr1[i]);
}
```

En este ejemplo tonto, puedes comprobar que hay posibilidades de fallo, si arr1 y arr2 no son iguales en tamaño, es fácil no ver que la longitud se tomaba de un array para recorrer el siguiente, especialmente si hay código entre medias.

Answer (score 0):

la única diferencia entre las dos primeras es el uso de memoria al declarar la variable "no es nada pero difiere jejejeje" con la ultima simplemente es mas cómodo para usar, teniendo en cuenta que no vas a usar un contador (la i del for)