# ¿Cuando se cuando tengo que usar un while o un do while?

Tags: java, bucle-for, while

Buenas queria saber cuando me doy cuenta cuando tengo que usar while o do while para realizar un programa , por que he visto gente que dice :
"no yo esto no lo haria con un for , podes usar el while o do while" .

Comment: while, do while y for son intercambiables siempre. No es una pregunta con mucho sentido. Los tres hacen lo mismo. Lo unico que pueden asegurar es la canitdad de veces que se va a ejecutar de seguro el bucle

Comment: @gbianchi do... while SIEMPRE se ejecuta al menos una vez

Comment: @PabloLozano ahi lo estaba aclarando ;)

Comment: Como dice @PabloLozano, "canonicamente" debes usar do..while si el bucle debe ejecutarse al menos una vez obligatoriamente, En caso contrario while. Aunque pueden ser intercambiables como dice gbianchi

Comment: `while (condición) {código}` evalúa al inicio, `do {código} while (condición)` evalúa al final del bloque (de código) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El bucle while y el bucle for en Java son intercambiables, es el bucle do.. while el que es un poco distinto, ya que los dos primeros comprueban la condición **antes** de ejecutar su bloque de código, mientras que el último lo hace **después** de ejecutarlo.

Puesto que la sintaxis de Java y Javascript son prácticamente iguales para este escenario, permíteme mostrar las diferencias con un ejemplo ejecutable en el navegador:

```js
let contador= 0;

do {
  console.log('El contador vale', contador);
  contador++;
} while (contador<0);

console.log('El contador vale al salir', contador);

contador = 0;
while (contador<0) {
  console.log('El contador vale', contador);
  contador++;
}

console.log('El contador vale al salir', contador);

for (contador=0; contador<0; contador++) {
  console.log('El contador vale', contador);
  contador++;
}

console.log('El contador vale al salir', contador);
```

Pregunta relacionada: [bucle for/for each](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102524/diferencia-entre-for-y-for-each)

Comment: Yo añadiría que si tienes muchas condiciones para salir del bucle, usar el while o el do-while